# Two classes in the same file

Tags: java

I have an issue with two classes in the same .java file.
This is the situation:

```
package pak1;

public class Example1 {

//some things`enter code here`
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

class Example2 {
//some things
}
```

My question is: how can I instantiate Example2 in others package (if it's possible)?

Comment: one public classe is possible in file .java

Comment: Then create an own file for that class. There is the reason to put two or more classes in one file if you need to access them from different classes?

Comment: As is stands? You Can't. That's why you don't normally add sibling classes to the same file.

Comment: You should accept an answer if it solves your problem or comment and reveal other details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two options:

- Move the second class to another file (recommended)
- Add the modifier `static` and put the second class into the first (nested class)

Comment: Eclipse told me `Illegal modifier for the class Example2; only public, abstract & final are permitted`

Comment: I just added a comment, but you should probably use another file anyway.

Comment: @yunandtidus 'Illegal Modifier'... that's because you didn't 'nest' Example2 ... a static class has to go 'inside' a parent class.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on from where you want to instantiate objects.

Since Example1 class is `public`, you can create instance of that class from anywhere.
But Example2 is having `default` access level. So you can only create instance from that class within your 
pak1 package only

Answer (score 0):

Adding public static is the key here, but you need to move the Example2 class in the Example 1

```
public class Example1 {

    // some things`enter code here`
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public static class Example2 {
        // some things
    }
}
```

And somewhere else :

```
new Example1 .Example2();
```

Comment: I guess this Question is not about Inner classes

Answer (score 0):

If you must have more than one `class` in the file that must be accessed from another package, you can always nest it.

```
public class Example1 {
    public class Example2 {

    }
}
```

Then access it with:

```
new Example1().new Example2()
```

Or move it to another file. Or make it `static`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try full qualified name. Like:

```
Blah blah = new other.package.Blah();
```